# BigNumber usage with Webpack + Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: BigNumberProvider
```

I'm starting project with `Webpack + Angular.JS` and I want to use `Bignumber.js` but can't include it.

The part of Webpack config:

```js
  resolve: {
      root: [path.join(__dirname, 'assets/libs/bower_components'), 'node_modules']
    },
    entry: {
      entry: ['./app/app.js'],
      vendor: [
          'lodash',
          'bignumber.js',
          'angular'
          ....
```

As it's library I do not include it as a dependency in my main app.js.
But I'm trying to inject it to my directive:

```js
app.directive('createpayment', [
      '$http',
      ' * ', // I've tried BigNumber, bignumber, binumber.js all of this doen't work
             // And there is nothing about this in README
      function($http, BigNumber ? , bignumber ? ) {
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I've already found an answer

Comment: And what was your solution to this? I'm looking for something similar with a number of libraries and an Angular app.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by utilizing the [`ProvidePlugin`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) plugin for webpack:

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    BigNumber: 'bignumber.js',
    lodash: 'lodash',
    $: 'jquery'
  }),
]
...
```

The `ProvidePlugin` definition assumes you have already added a `resolve` declaration to your webpack configuration.

Comment: Thank you for this, I used it to resolve an issue with a coupe of other Javascript modules like BigNumber that I'm using in my Angular app which I'm wrapping inside Webpack.